# Passing a value back to a suitescript page

Tags: netsuite

I am using the reference cart Denali in NetSuites SSP.  I have the following code set up in a customer folder for suitescript\LiveOrder.Model.js.

If I hard code in a value for "num" it will successfully provide the response I am looking for, so my code seems to be working correctly.

I cannot figure out how to pass "num" from the front end cart.summary.view.js to suitescript\LiveOrder.Model.js so that I can use it in this search.

```
  var filters = [
      new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_owner', null, 'anyof', nlapiGetUser()),
      new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', num)
    ];
    var columns = [
      new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'),
      new nlobjSearchColumn('name'),
      new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_genre'),
      new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_transfertime')
    ];
    var search = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_artist', null, filters, columns);
        result.internalid= search[0].getValue('internalid'),
        result.name= search[0].getValue('name'),
        result.genre= search[0].getValue('custrecord_genre'),
        result.transfertime= search[0].getValue('custrecord_transfertime')
```

What is the best way to handle passing a value from the front end, to the back end in the reference cart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery post method to pass data from frond end to backend in SSP application. You can then retrieve the parameter using request.getParameter in .ss file then you can apply in your search.